# I would like to Select data in between two dates from from my server. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve data in between two dates which the user will select from the dropdown lists.

I have tried something: Here's my code.

```
string dateFrom = DropDownList1.Text.ToString();
            string dateTo = DropDownList2.Text.ToString();

            string myconstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KanbanConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconstring))
            {
                DataTable dat = new DataTable();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM city.xls WHERE Date BETWEEN @dateFrom AND  @dateTo"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dateFrom);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dateTo);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    da.Fill(dat);
                    D2.DataSource = dat;
                    D2.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

I am supposed to get the data in a datatable which is D2.
However I get an error like this:

> Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: check that you have a connection string called kanBanConnectionString in your config file

Comment: @Programnik yes i do.

Comment: You are missing this `cmd.Connection = conn`

Comment: don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked.

```
DateTime dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(DropDownList1.Text);
            DateTime dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(DropDownList2.Text);

            string myconstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KanbanConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconstring))
            {
                DataTable dat = new DataTable();
                string find = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE Date BETWEEN @dateFrom AND  @dateTo";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(find, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dateFrom);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dateTo);
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    da.Fill(dat);
                    D2.DataSource = dat;
                    D2.DataBind();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

add the connection initialization

```
cmd.connection=conn;
```

then you are good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM city.xls WHERE Date BETWEEN @dateFrom AND  @dateTo"))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dateFrom);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dateTo);                           
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        da.Fill(dat);
                        D2.DataSource = dat;
                        D2.DataBind();
                    }
```

Comment: You need to use the open connection to create the command, or create the command using the open connection.  Google the syntax for the correct thing, but basically you are not connecting the command with the connection.